# How to implement MongoDB nested query in c# dotnet

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, serialization

I have a MongoDB collection in the following format.

```
{
  "_id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "createdDate": "2022-07-09T20:25:38.8275833-03:00",
  "active": true,
  "PersonType": "PF",
  "CompanyName": "Teste Name",
  "TradingName": "Teste Nickname",
  "Documents": [
    {
      "_t": "Cpf",
      "type": "Cpf",
      "number": "49259564000"
    },
    {
      "_t": "RG",
      "type": "RG",
      "number": "925956408"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I try to get a document by Id or even the entire collection of documents, the Documents array always returns empty.

[image]

These are the repository query methods

```
        public virtual async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> GetAllAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            return await dbCollection.Find(filterBuilder.Empty).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        public virtual async Task<T> GetAsync(Guid id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            FilterDefinition<T> filter = filterBuilder.Eq(entity => entity.Id, id);

            return await dbCollection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
```

1. Why is the list of Documents returned not deserialized and returns empty?
2. What is needed for the Documents list to be returned?

Comment: I don't understand the question, your screenshot contains the returned data

Comment: Add the query you use and one example of the data you expect to get.

Comment: Inside the object there is a class that stores a list of personal documents, called **Documents**, and this list is being returned empty.

Comment: I use this query.

Comment: I use this query.

```
public virtual async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> GetAllAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            return await dbCollection.Find(filterBuilder.Empty).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
```

And the object should be returned like this, with the Documents array filled:

```
Active: true,
CompanyName: "teste Name",
CreatedDate: {09/07/2022 20:25:38 -03:00},
Documents: [
    {
      "type": "Cpf",
      "number": "49259564000"
    },
    {
      "type": "RG",
      "number": "925956408"
    }
  ],
  
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of documents was being returned empty, due to the fact that in the Document class the Documents property was set private. After making the change according to the image, the list is returned with the populated documents.

[image]